# Using ContourPlot3D to plot a double spheroid model

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot 2 spheroids that connect smoothly at z=0 and show spheroid1 where z>0 and show spheroid2 where z<0. But I can't differentiate the two according to the z range. This is my code.

```
Module[{a = 1.12*10^-3, b = 1.09*10^-3, c = 0.82*10^-3, 
  z0 = 0.73*10^-3},
 ContourPlot3D[{(x^2 + y^2)/a^2 + z^2/b^2 == 
    1, (x^2 + y^2)/a^2 + z^2/c^2 == 1},
  {x, -1.5 a, 1.5 a}, {y, -1.5 a, 1.5 a}, {z, -c, b},
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x < 0 || y > 0],
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
  ContourStyle -> {Yellow, Magenta}]
 ]
```

I would like to see the yellow part at z>0 and the magenta part at z<0

(would like to plot only the upper half of the yellow part and the lower half of the magenta)
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the [`ClipPlanes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipPlanes.html) option in [`ContourStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourStyle.html).  However in version 11.0.1 the [`MeshStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html) and [`BoundaryStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryStyle.html) do not consider the `ContourStyle` `ClipPlanes` option so must be set to `None` to prevent plotting extra mesh lines.  I think this may be a bug.

```
Module[{a = 1.12*10^-3, b = 1.09*10^-3, c = 0.82*10^-3, z0 = 0.73*10^-3},
 ContourPlot3D[
  {(x^2 + y^2)/a^2 + z^2/b^2 == 1,
   (x^2 + y^2)/a^2 + z^2/c^2 == 1},
  {x, -1.5 a, 1.5 a}, {y, -1.5 a, 1.5 a}, {z, -c, b},
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x < 0 || y > 0],
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
  ContourStyle -> {
    {Yellow, ClipPlanes -> {{0, 0, 1, 0}}},
    {Magenta, ClipPlanes -> {{0, 0, -1, 0}}}
    },
  MeshStyle -> None,
  BoundaryStyle -> None
  ] ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

The desired plot can be obtained by a single call to `ContourPlot3D` by plotting only the top half of the outer spheroid and the bottom half of the inner spheroid, each with its own color.

```
Module[{a = 1.12*10^-3, b = 1.09*10^-3, c = 0.82*10^-3, 0 = 0.73*10^-3},
    ContourPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2)/a^2 + If[z > 0, z^2/b^2 , z^2/c^2] == 1, 
    {x, -1.5 a, 1.5 a}, {y, -1.5 a, 1.5 a}, {z, -c, b},
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x < 0 || y > 0],
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, LabelStyle -> {14, Bold}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, f}, If[z > 0, Yellow, Magenta]]]
]
```

[image]

Comment: +1; although I recommend using [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) rather than [`If`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) in a function/equation. `Piecewise` is better behaved, e.g., it can be differentiated.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) to display two separate plots

```
Module[
 {a = 1.12*10^-3, b = 1.09*10^-3,
  c = 0.82*10^-3, z0 = 0.73*10^-3, m},
 m = 3 a/2;
 Show[
  ContourPlot3D[
   (x^2 + y^2)/a^2 + z^2/b^2 == 1,
   {x, -m, m}, {y, -m, m}, {z, -c, b},
   RegionFunction ->
    Function[{x, y, z}, z > 0 && (x < 0 || y > 0)],
   ContourStyle -> Yellow],
  ContourPlot3D[
   (x^2 + y^2)/a^2 + z^2/c^2 == 1,
   {x, -m, m}, {y, -m, m}, {z, -c, b},
   RegionFunction ->
    Function[{x, y, z}, z < 0 && (x < 0 || y > 0)],
   ContourStyle -> Magenta],
  AxesLabel ->
   (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y, z}),
  PlotPoints -> 75]]
```

[image]